# What if layout height is longer than device height in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Please take a look at screen shot from simulator for iphone 8 plus. (01.png) Here is my question: I cant see whole view of my page(i cant see whole part of button5 and button6 because there is no vertical scroll bar) Shouldn't vertical scroll bar appear automatically? If vertical scroll bar appears then i can reach bottom of the page. What should i do? Please give me an advice because i haven't founded any solution yet. You can also take a look at screen shot from xcode main story board to see height of button5 and button 6. (02.png) I mean page background should not move. But I should be able to scrolling up and down through on page. Thanks.
[01.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEf4z.png)
[02.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikek.png)

Comment: Use free-form size

Comment: You can use either `UICollectionView` for dynamic content or `UIScrollView` for static content.

Comment: dear @Bista free-form size means simulated metrics > Size and then selecting Freeform. do you mean this ? it does not work if you mean this. thanks

Comment: Scroll bars do not *automatically* appear if the content is larger than the screen. You have a few choices. (1) As already stated, place your **static** content in something that *does* provide a scroll bar - as in `UICollectionView`, `UIScrollView`, even a `UITableView`. (2) Learn to use auto layout and constraints. But to be honest, I have to downvite your question *as is* because you've provided no code, no detail, nothing that can actually help anyone to know **what** the real issue is.

Comment: @Bista . Yes, it works. thanks to everyone.

Comment: How can i mark my question is solved ? I can not see any button to do it. Can you help me please ? We should do it. @Bista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add image view with background image below all components in the ViewController.

Then add Scroll View with your content on top of that image view.

Don't forget to select clear colour as the background for scroll view and the inner view apart from your buttons.

Follow this tutorial to add Scroll view and content in it directly in storyboard using Interface builder.
https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7